# Android re-showing dialogfragment from separate fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-dialog, android-dialogfragment

I have an application that is using fragments.  The set up is like so:
Main Activity loads, loads fragment activity into right portion of parent activity
-From the Fragment, I launch a DialogFragment which displays a list of users
-From the DialogFragment, if you click on one of the users in the list, it hides the list of users DialogFragment .hide() and shows a new DialogFragment containing the details about the user

This all works great.  However, when I click the Close button on the Details DialogFragment, I'd like to dismiss() that dialog, and re-show the List of Users dialog.

I realize this is somewhat difficult to follow.
Does anyone have any insight that may help me?

**UPDATE**

The code I use to display the DialogFragment is the following:

```
MyDialogFragment dialog = new MyDialogFragment();
dialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "MyDialogFragment");
```

Then once in the dialog fragment, if I wanted to hide it and show the details fragment  I call

```
dialog.hide();
MyDetailsFragment details = new MyDetailsFragment();
details.show(getFragmentManager(), "MyDetailsFragment");
```

Basically I need to be able to re-show the dialog above when I dismiss the details.

Comment: One solution that doesn't involve `DialogFragment`s at all is to use `Dialog`-themed Activities (the backstack will ensure that the list-of-users activity dialog will be re-shown when the user-details activity dialog is finished). You could probably achieve something similar using the `FragmentTransaction#addToBackStack` method as well.

Comment: Could you show an example of the code you use to bring up the DialogFragments and switch them out?

Comment: @AndrewSchuster question has been updated to contain the code I use to show/hide the dialog fragments

Comment: Have you tried not calling `hide()` on your `MyDialogFragment`?

Comment: @AndrewSchuster Yes, and that does seem to work but you can see the dialog pop overtop of the MyDialogFragment.  Then when you dismiss the details dialog, the dialog below is already there and present.  Was hoping to be able to make it smoother by hiding one, showing the other, and when the details is dismissed, re-show the hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a fragment transaction is performed, you can add it to the back stack which can be reversed on dismissing the dialog.

Begin a fragment transaction and use the [DialogFragment.show(FragmentTransaction transaction, String tag)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#show(android.app.FragmentTransaction,%20java.lang.String)) variant which takes the `FragmentTransaction` as parameter. It will take care of showing the Dialog, adding the fragment to the passed transaction and then committing the transaction. Later when the Dialog is dismissed, `DialogFragment` will itself take care of popping the transaction.

You can follow the first sample posted in the [DialogFragment docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html).

Here is the working code:

```
   public void launchMyDialog(View v) {
        // DialogFragment.show() will take care of adding the fragment
        // in a transaction.  We also want to remove any currently showing
        // dialog, so make our own transaction and take care of that here.
        FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        Fragment prev = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("mydialog");
        if (prev != null) {
            ft.remove(prev);
        }
        ft.addToBackStack(null);

        MyDialogFragment dialog = new MyDialogFragment();
        dialog.show(ft, "mydialog");
    }

    public static class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
            Button b = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button);
            b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                    Fragment prev = getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("mydialog");
                    if (prev != null) {
                        ft.remove(prev);
                    }
                    ft.addToBackStack(null);

                    MyDetailsFragment dialog = new MyDetailsFragment();
                    dialog.show(ft, "mydialog");

                }

            });
            return v;
        }
    }
```